# How to transform an object into an array of objects without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, transform

## How can I transform this object into an array with objects inside ?

```
beacons = {
    "key": {
        "one": "char",
        "two": "sue",
        "three": "johnny"
    },
    "key2": {
        "one": "char",
        "two": "sue",
        "three": "johnny"
    },
    "key3": {
        "one": "char",
        "two": "cara",
        "three": "johnny"
    }
}
```

Te result should be like the one below and should I call the properties in a way like this: **beaconsArray[1].one ---> "char"**

```
beaconsArray = [{
    "one": "char",
    "two": "sue",
    "three": "johnny"
}, {
    "one": "char",
    "two": "sue",
    "three": "johnny"
}, {
    "one": "char",
    "two": "sue",
    "three": "johnny"
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the order may not be stable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
Thanks for the code block corrections! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var beacons = {
"key": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key2": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key3": { "one": "char", "two": "cara", "three": "johnny" }
};

var beaconsArray = [];
for(var key in beacons) {
 beaconsArray.push(beacons[key]);
}

console.log(beaconsArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating.

For a stable result you may need to sort the keys previously.

```js
var beacons = { "key": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key2": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key3": { "one": "char", "two": "cara", "three": "johnny" } },
    array = Object.keys(beacons).sort().map(function (k) { return beacons[k]; });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sure would be nice if SE would [***finally** get around to doing this*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console/279987#279987) so you don't have to have that CSS...

Comment: right, it's a pity to use css for the console, better would be a dynamic size with a handle.

Comment: I think this code is pretty useful even without the css. Thank you @NinaScholz =D

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan: Yes. The CSS is only there to make the console fill the result pane, because months later, SE still haven't added a UI for console options.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var beacons = { "key": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key2": { "one": "char", "two": "sue", "three": "johnny" }, "key3": { "one": "char", "two": "cara", "three": "johnny" } }
var result = [];

for (key in beacons) {
  result.push(beacons[key]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will do this for you.

```
var beaconsArray = Object.values(beacons);
```

It's important to note that this isn't officially part of the JS spec yet, and as such browser support is very limited. **Don't rely on this without a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js)** unless you know for sure your users are going to be on the latest versions of Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I get "Object.values is not a function(…)" on this.
I dunno why. It seems pretty much what I want to by its documentation =O

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Whoops, too used to transpilers, that's my bad! Will edit!

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan: As TJ Crowder said, this isn't a standardized feature yet - newer versions of Chrome and Firefox implement it, but that's about it.